# Changing fonts don't apply to all places

Tags: fonts, customization

I tweaked fonts and still some places showing Ubuntu font. You can see them here:

[image]

[image]

How can I change fonts for all places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is *font substitution*. Because those texts have predefined fonts for them and as long as your system can recognize *Ubuntu* font (which was the defined font for that notice), those will be rendered as such.

Create a file in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d` folder with name say `09-replace-ubuntu.conf` (the name should end with `.conf` extension). The content of the file should be like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">

<fontconfig>
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Ubuntu</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Segoe UI</string></edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

What it does is it whenever the system queries for *Ubuntu* font and it responds with your preferred/overridden choice, here it is *Segoe UI*.

Here is a picture of the same notice with replaced *Segoe UI* font.

[image: ubuntu notice with segoe font]